# Global Admin - cannot see Billing - Unauthorized

Tags: azure

I'm global admin and subcription owner

[image]

But when click on Billing-Cost analysis getting

```
Customer does not have the privilege to see the cost
```

Am i missing something ?

[image]

Comment: Are you checking in same tenant or Partner tenant?

Comment: In the same tenant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenant is managed by CSP, didn't know it until i tried to create support case to MS and got following error:

[image]

After that got access to Partner center and performed below steps:
http://www.mistercloudtech.com/2022/04/25/how-to-enable-a-csp-customer-to-view-azure-usage-charges/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a missing permission on the subscription. The impacted user should have one of the [following roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/manage-billing-access#give-others-access-to-view-billing-information):

- Service Administrator
- Co-administrator
- Owner
- Contributor
- Reader
- Billing reader

Kindly assign one of the above roles to the user on the targeted subscription (I am using service administrator) by following [Assign a user as an administrator of an Azure subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal-subscription-admin)

For current admins kindly see classic admins tab:

[image]

Comment: I'm subscription owner.